# jaxb auto generate 'type' field when serializing inherited class

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs

I am creating a REST service using jax-rs in Java. I have the following models:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({Student.class, Teacher.class})
public abstract class Person {    
    @XmlElement
    public String name;
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Student extends Person {

    @XmlElement
    public int classNo;
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Teacher extends Person {

    @XmlElement
    public String qualification;
}
```

I created a class to package the response as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class PersonResponse {

    @XmlElement
    public Person person;
}
```

Now, I have the following resource class:

```
@Path("person")
public class ApiResource {

    @GET
    @Path("student")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public PersonResponse student() {
        Student person = new Student();
        person.name = "Steve";
        person.classNo = 5;
        PersonResponse response = new PersonResponse();
        response.person = person;
        return response;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("teacher")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public PersonResponse teacher() {
        Teacher person = new Teacher();
        person.name = "John";
        person.qualification = "Math";
        PersonResponse response = new PersonResponse();
        response.person = person;
        return response;
    }
}
```

When I access the `student` endpoint, I get the following result:

```
{"person":{"type":"student","name":"Steve","classNo":5}}
```

And when I access the `teacher` endpoint, I get the following result:

```
{"person":{"type":"teacher","name":"John","qualification":"Math"}}
```

As you see, there is an extra field `'type'` derived for the name of the inherited classes `Teacher` and `Student`.

I wonder how to disable auto-generating this field?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid type field? Think about deserialization process where in deserializer has to identify the correct Type before deserializing it. Try removing XmlSeeAlso annotation to see what happens

Comment: The field name `type` is reserved for something else in my real app. But you have the point about deserialization. Removing the annotation will not help, because in this case, the whole serialization will not work :(